# Bad parceable Exception

Tags: android, entity, parcelable

I always get bad parceable exception on my custom entity.
I have follow all rules but not getting where the problem is.
Below is my class:

```
    public class SubChannelsEntity implements Parcelable{
    public SubChannelsEntity() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    SubChannelsEntity(Parcel in){
        if (in.readString()!=null)
        this.imageUrl = in.readString();
        if (in.readString()!=null)
        this.name=in.readString();
        if (in.readString()!=null)
        this.id=in.readString();
        if (in.readString()!=null)
        this.Thumb_image1=in.readString();
    }
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

   public  static final Parcelable.Creator<SubChannelsEntity> CREATOR= new Parcelable.Creator<SubChannelsEntity>() {
        @Override
        public SubChannelsEntity createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new SubChannelsEntity(in);
        }
        @Override
        public SubChannelsEntity[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SubChannelsEntity[size];
        }

    };
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (this.imageUrl!=null)
        dest.writeString(this.imageUrl);
        if (this.name!=null)
        dest.writeString(this.name);
        if (this.id!=null)
        dest.writeString(this.id);
        if (this.Thumb_image1!=null)
        dest.writeString(this.Thumb_image1);
    }
    /*@Override
    public String toString() {

        return "\ngetImageUrl\t: " + getImageUrl() + "\n\ngetName\t\t: " + getName()+ "\n\ngetId\t\t: " + getId();

    }*/
    String imageUrl,name,id,Thumb_image1;

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setThumb_image1(String thumb_image1) {
        Thumb_image1 = thumb_image1;
    }

    public String getThumb_image1() {
        return Thumb_image1;
    }
}
```

Below is my logcat:

> ComponentInfo{toteflix.com/com.intersoft.youngcutsmovies.DashboardActivity2}:
>   android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a
>   Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class
>   com.intersoft.youngcutsmovies.entities.SubChannelsEntity at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) at`
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
>   at

Comment: are you using proguard? Can you mark `CREATOR`  `public static final` ?

Comment: Its still crashing and giving me same exception... plz help

Comment: are you using proguard? If you don't know it, can you check the value of minifyEnabled in your gradle file ?

Comment: its minifyEnabled false

Comment: are the strings all != from null

Comment: I have updated my class can u check? is it ok now

Comment: can you mark `SubChannelsEntity(Parcel in)` public ?

Comment: Thanku so much buddy. it works.... yes the problem was constructor

Comment: did it work ? Was it  the constructor ?